# Mach-O Magic and Cigam Clarification

Tags: hex, executable, mach-o

I am currently making an advanced Mach-O Executable Disassembler and Am confused about the Magic and Cigam part of an Executable Header. I understand how they work and how they determine the byte order of the executable and if its 32/64-Bit but the one thing I am stuck on is this:
which hexadecimal order represent Magic and Cigam:

This is the raw hexadecimal of a Common Header (straight from hexdump):

`cffaedfe` - This is a 64-Bit Header but is it Magic or Cigam.

The reason I am confused with this is because of all the ordering like cigam requires flipping every 4 bytes in the opposite direction and do I read the bytes in Endianness or not??? I've looked at the mach headers and I've found this stuff:

MH_MAGIC_64 = 0xfeedfacf

MH_CIGAM_64 = 0xcffaedfe (MH_MAGIC swapped)

but is 0xcffaedfe meant to be matched from the direct hexadecimal from the mach-o file meaning its CIGAM or do I read it in Endian and `cffaedfe` becomes `feedfacf` making it MAGIC????

just please tell me:

(direct from file hexdump) `cffaedfe` - Is this Magic Or Cigam????

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MH_MAGIC_64` and `MH_CIGAM_64` don't have some absolute endianness attached to them, their meaning is relative to the host endianness.

Let's say you have binary A for a little endian architecture with its first four bytes `cf fa ed fe`, and a binary B for a big endian architecture with its first four bytes `fe ed fa cf`.

On a little endian machine, binary A will have `MH_MAGIC_64` and binary B will have `MH_CIGAM_64`, but on a big endian machine binary B will have `MH_MAGIC_64` and A will have `MH_CIGAM_64`.

So in essence, you read the magic using your native host byte order and if it matches `MH_CIGAM_64`, then you're gonna have to swap around all integers you read from that binary.

Comment: How to I find out if my machine is using little endian or big endian?

Comment: `uint16_t u = 1; printf("%s endian\n", *(uint8_t*)&u ? "little" : "big");`